# Can GitHub PAT's be used across orgs?

Tags: github

Is it possible to use the same Github PAT created in one SAML protected org in another SAML protected org if they are under the same enterprise?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to use a token across multiple orgs using SAML, whether they are part of the same enterprise or not.  In the PAT settings, you'll need to enable the PAT for each specific SAML organization you want to use.  Click the “Enable SSO” or “Disable SSO” drop-down and choose “Authorize” for each org.

Comment: This works with classic tokens, but not the fine-grained tokens capability that was added recently (and still in beta).